# How can I completely alter my Django database schema without losing any data?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm making some big changes to the schema of my database, but I don't want to lose any data in the process of migrating to the new schema. Let me provide a specific example. I currently have a `class Person(models.Model)`, and each `Person` instance has a bunch of data associated with it like a `name`, `age`, etc. There are already many `Person` instances in my database. I now realize that I actually need two types of `Person`, a `Student` and a `Teacher`, and each of those types will have their own unique variables and methods. It seems to me that the best way to accomplish this is by making `Person` an abstract class and making `Student` and `Teacher` extend that class. Some of variables in `Person` currently only apply to `Student`, so I want to move those variables into the `Student` subclass.

In general, how could I go about doing this migration without losing any data? I'm fairly new to Django, so I don't really know where to start except that I probably need to write some kind of custom script to be run with `python manage.py`.

Comment: You can also add a person_type field with a choices . https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices

Comment: The problem with that approach is that what I want to do really lends itself to subclassing because `Student` and `Teacher` each have their own, separate variables and methods, but also a lot of shared variables. It makes no sense for a `Teacher` to have a GPA, but both a `Student` and a `Teacher` have last names. That is just one example.

Comment: If you are using postgres, you can explore using hstorefield for some level of flexibility in fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is Django [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

1. Add `abstract = True` to you person meta model
2. Add your `Student` and `Teacher` models and have them inherit from `Person`
3. run `manage.py makemigrations`
4. The resulting migration will have operations that add your new models and remove `Person`. Your custom data migration operation needs to come after the creation and before the delete. Follow the Django docs example that migrates the name field on the `Person` model but instead, create instances of the new `Student` and `Teacher` models for each person. Be sure to save the new instances.

Other tips:

1. Use [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/) to backup your data so that you can easily restore
   it in the event you make a mistake during migration
2. It would be prudent to rename your new special migration to make it more easily identifiable by you in the future